# How to include a second parameter to function store(Request $request) using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 8.x, php 7.3.
I need to include the $id as the second parameter in the function store(Request $request).

Some people say use arrays, others say cookies.

This is what I have:

```
Route::post('/memorys/{id}', [App\Http\MemorysController::class, 'store']);
```

In my create form:

```
<form name="f1" action="{{url('/memorys/{$event->id}')}}"  method="POST">
```

How can I pass a second parameter?

Comment: you don't pass anything since you are not the calling of the `store` method ... What you have there would be passing a route parameter to the `store` method as that is what the route parameter does so ... what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store data so don't pass the ID; remove this id. Change your route simply add this route:

```
Route::post('/memorys', 'App\Http\MemorysController@store');
```

And use like so:

```
<form name="f1" action="{{route('/memorys.store')}} method="POST">
```

If you updated data so you can pass the ID.